# Capturing the positions of "start" and "end" markers in a multi-line string

Tags: python, regex

Is there any better (and shorter) way to get index of a regex match in Python?

```
import re
sstring = """
this is dummy text
which starts with nothing
and ends with something
"""

starts = re.finditer('start[s]?', sstring)
ends = re.finditer('end[s]?', sstring)

for m in starts:
    print (m.start())

for m in ends:
    print (m.end())
```

For me, there is only one `starts` and `ends`match in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that there is exactly one match, then you don't need to iterate.  You could write:

```
start, end = re.search('start.*ends?', sstring, re.DOTALL).span()
```

To note:

- Take advantage of [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) so that the regex can span multiple lines.
- Use [`match.span()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.span) and destructuring assignment to get both the `start` and `end` in one statement.
- The `[s]?` after `start` is, from a mechanical viewpoint, useless.  You might want to keep it just for symmetry.

The spacing in `print (something)` is kind of weird; `print(something)` would be more conventional.

Answer (score 1):

I am no python expert but I think if the pattern contains only one match group we can use `re.search(pattern, string).start()` method instead of `iter` object.

```
print(re.search('start[s]?', sstring).start())
print(re.search('end[s]?', sstring).end())
```

Comment: We expect an answer to contain an actual review. This is not a review. Please add an actual review to your answer or risk this answer getting removed.

Comment: I am new to codereview. I will look at how to for this group.